# When I click on login the url gets updated with parameters but session is not created?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, authentication, devise

I am using devise for authentication. Recently when I integrated bootstrap into my rails app the devise login system stopped working.

When I enter the email and password the URL gets updated with the parameters of the user but I am not getting redirected to the homepage and the session is not getting created.

As I am using the logged in condition to display the options in the navbar and the logout option is not showing so I think the session is not getting created.

Like the normal URL of the signin page is,

```
https://example.com/users/sign_in
```

after I click on the login button after entering my details, the url changes to this I stay at the login page.

```
https://example.com/users/sign_in?utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=OeR8e3thZu4SnUQeNO8zYpHJ4vWMxiIaWcHkEbRDb9o%3D&user[email]=na.nishantarora%40gmail.com&user[password]=hashfloat&user[remember_me]=0&commit=Log+in
```

I am not able to figure out where the problem is, I have tried adding a method in my application controller for redirection but it didn't work. Here is the method I tried using,

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
        current_user
  end
```

Over that I also want the user to get redirected to his own profile after he logs in to the website.

and here is what my routes file looks like,

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'static_pages/home'

  get 'static_pages/help'

  devise_for :users
  resources :users
 root 'static_pages#home'
end
```

Comment: Seems like you are submiting form using GET method instead of POST. Check it in your view.

Comment: Here is what my routes file looks like, I am using directly the devise for users method and as far as I know it takes care of the rest.

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'static_pages/home'

  get 'static_pages/help'

  devise_for :users
  resources :users
 root 'static_pages#home'
end